# Wait for update to complete before starting other update in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**What I have**

I am building an android app where I have a document containing a field named as *issued*

When a specific button in my app is pressed, the currently value of issued is fetched and incremented by 1 and a new document with this new value of issued is also made.

**Issue**

Currently, an issue i am facing (most probably due to some latency delay) is that when the button is clicked it takes some time(usually seconds) to update the value in the issued field. However, if i open my app on another device and click that button on both devices at approximately the same time, eventually what happens is that both phones fetch the old value of issued and the one which completes the task first makes the document first and when the other device completes the task, the document is overwritten.

**What I expect**

I am expecting a behavior in which the person who clicks later (even if a few milliseconds), that person should be assigned new number and both should not be fetching the same value.

[image]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Since you mention incrementing values, you might want to have a look at Firestore's built-in [atomic increment operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

Comment: As far as I'm reading the problem, Firestore transactions would be helpful for your requirement. A transaction [re-tries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#data_contention_in_the_mobileweb_sdks) database operations if the data being worked with changes (in this case a client would re-fetch the document containing the `issued` field if it was changed by another client during the transaction taking place). You should post the database structure, and the relevant code to confirm these details as Frank mentioned.